# Bytecode from online version of remix at https://remix.ethereum.org/ on Firefox is a string of chars

Tags: solidity, remix

I am running solidity 0.8 contract on remix online in Firefox browser/MacOS. After compiling the contract, the byte code returned is just a huge chunk of random chars string which is completely unreadable. Here is a portion of it:

```
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
```

The Abu returned seems all right. However the byte code seems garbish. What's the issue here? Problem with remix?

Here is the remix compiler setup being use:

[image]

Comment: Bitecode all right.
You can open https://www.evm.codes/playground?fork=shanghai&unit=Wei&codeType=Bytecode 
Paste the obtained code and you will get executable procedures in EVM

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov  Thanks for the answer. I only notice the change because the byte code is passed in as JSON obj and my app is applying JSON.parse(byte code) on it. JSON.parse throws error on the byte code which is actually a string. Can byte code be a string or JSON obj?

Comment: Bytecode is exactly what you pasted above, if you are using hardhat and ethers, then you don't need to worry about all these. Lemme know what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: Remix may show byte code differently.
If you look through Compilation Detais -> BYTECODE you will see bytecode in json structure.
If you copy to clipboard via Bytecode item (next to ABI) you will get such an array as shown above.

Comment: I guess I must see the byte code in json format before with remix and that's why applying JSON.parse . I always use copy to clipboard on remix. Is bytecode in hex string or in JSON format controllable?  If JSON.parse applied to a string, it will throws an error and code has to take this into consideration when retrieving byte code for a contract.

Comment: Ethers 5.7.x is being used here. The byte code is used for deploying a contract.